# Nested foreach statements with conditional

Tags: php, foreach, conditional-statements, nested-loops

I have the following XML Data:

```
<MEET>
    <CLASS>
        <NAME>Professional</NAME>
    </CLASS>
    <CLASS>
        <NAME>Amateur</NAME>
    </CLASS>
    <EVENT>
        <NAME>Event One</NAME>
    </EVENT>
    <EVENT>
        <NAME>Event Two</NAME>
    </EVENT>
    <EVENT>
        <NAME>Event Three</NAME>
    </EVENT>
    <ATHLETE>
        <NAME>Joe Smith</NAME>
        <ADDRESS>123 Main St, Anytown, NY 12121</ADDRESS>
        <EMAIL>joe@smith.com</EMAIL>
        <PHONE>518-555-1234</PHONE>
        <EMERGENCYNAME>Jane Smith</EMERGENCYNAME>
        <EMERGENCYPHONE>518-555-5678</EMERGENCYPHONE>
        <CLASS>Amateur</CLASS>
    </ATHLETE>
</MEET>
```

And the following PHP:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('url');
foreach ($xml->CLASS as $classes) {
    echo '<h1>'.$classes->NAME.'</h1>';
    foreach ($xml->EVENT as $events) {
        echo '<h2>'.$classes->NAME.': '.$events->NAME.'</h2>';
        foreach($xml->ATHLETE as $athletes) {
            if (strpos($athletes->CLASS, $classes->NAME) !== false) {
                echo $athletes->NAME;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

And I cannot get Joe Smith's name to output beneath the H1 `Amateur` heading, under the H2 `Amateur: Event One` `Amateur: Event Two` and `Amateur: Event Three` subheadings.

If I replace the `$needle` in my strpos with Amateur, it outputs Joe Smith in every event in BOTH classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `var_dump` function to see what is the instance of your variable, it could show you that the type of `$athletes->CLASS` and `$classes->NAME` are `SimpleXMLElement`.

If you want to compare them together you must change your `if` statement to something like this:

```
if (strpos($athletes->CLASS->__toString(), $classes->NAME->__toString()) !== false) {
    echo $athletes->NAME;
}
```

Comment: It may not be necessary to call `__toString` on `$athletes->CLASS`, since `strpos` expects a string for the first argument it may be automatically converted. (I'm not sure.)

Comment: @Don'tPanic you appear to be correct. Using __toString on $classes->NAME only also appears to work

Comment: @whakawaehere yes, that one definitely is required - note the strpos docs _"If needle is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character."_

Comment: @Don'tPanic, It doesn't matter even `strpos` convert it to a string by itself, we must follow the standards! When a method expects a string, it's really better for us to give a string to it! It can save us from probably bugs and issues later (also if you just use an object instead of a string, there will be a _warning_ in the logs...

Comment: @HamidYousefi I don't think it's a bad practice to use an object that we know has a `__toString` magic method in a context where a string is expected. That's what `toString` is for, and it doesn't cause a warning. Regardless, I didn't intend to criticize your answer. It's a fine answer. Just offering some extra info, and anyone who reads it can take it or leave it.